# Pass Object Array as a parameter to a JSONP

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

I have a object like:

```
var my_component = {};
```

Later I assign some properties to it.

```
my_component.ID = 1;
my_component.Name = 'test_user';
```

There are large numbers of object like this.

How can i pass this as a parameter to JSONP Enabled WebService.

I only know i can pass the string, or bool but i want to pass the object and/or object arrays.

Do i need to class of same type but how on the server side.

I am using WCF services for the same.

Do i need to create DATA contracts that will be the parameters

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your object into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify(my_component)`. For compatibility with IE, you can include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

On server side i need to use the class to convert a string back to array

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        obj user = jss.Deserialize<obj>(JsonString);
```

Here obj is the name of the object.

Comment: What should be the parameter type of Function on server side? Can you please specify, should it be a string if it is than how can i convert back to object on server side

Comment: If it's a "JSONP enabled webservice" it should be able to handle stringified JSON. Pretty much every language there is includes a JSON parser.

Comment: @Great wroked for me i need to use built in .Net Class for the same to convert a string back to an object